# Fast.ai & NLP: Remove unknown words in fast.ai tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, fast-ai

I'm building an NLP model to classify real estate text. The issue is that, when creating a data bunch, many of the words are given an `xxunk` special token.

The code I used to generate a TextClasDataBunch object:

```
count = 0
error = True
while error:
    try: 
        data_clas = TextClasDataBunch.from_csv(path, 'text.csv', vocab=data_lm.train_ds.vocab, bs=2)
        error = False
        print(f'failure count is {count}\n')    
    except:
        count = count + 1
        print(f'failure count is {count}')
```

The code above classifies `parcel control number, property account number, parcel id, Property SBL, and PARID` as `xxbos parcel xxunk number,xxbos parcel number,xxbos xxunk xxunk,xxbos xxunk acres,xxbos xxmaj xxunk`. The preponderance of `xxunk` is likely decreasing the effectiveness of my model.

Is there a way to include rare words in the fast.ai tokenizer? I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993922/how-to-include-rare-words-in-fast-ai-tokenizer-for-nlp) question, but there's currently no answer.

Answer (score 0):

The treatment of unknowns depends on the task. In general, keeping 'xxunk' is good. But if you want to remove it, you may specify the vocab you want to work with.

Besides, consider moving your code to fastai v2 if possible. It is much easier to work with and better documented.